# Why is the first line automatically indented by one space?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

`line with backtick or code block

line with backtick or code block`

Why is the first line automatically indented by one space when using backticks or `<code>` tags to surround multiple lines?

Is this intentional or a design flaw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The padding of the `<code>` element is set to `1px 5px 1px 5px`, thus indenting the left and right by five pixels. This makes sense because inline `code` needs to be properly spaced and it'd look weird without the padding.

Why does it look weird when using it for multiple lines? Because `<code>` is not meant for that. `<code>` is for inline formatting. You should use `<pre></pre>` instead if you want a block element.

Compare the incorrect backtick / `<code>` variant:

```
<code>multiline  
foo</code>
```

Which renders as:

`multiline

foo`

And the correct:

```
<pre>
multiline
foo
</pre>
```

Which renders as:

```
multiline
foo
```

Always use the latter for multiline code. You can of course indent code by four spaces as well to achieve the same thing. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to indent selected text with our editor.

```
    multiline
    foo
```

Comment: Hm, I stumbled upon this while trying to correct [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/630568/multiple-bsod-windows-7). Now, If I replace `<code>` with `<pre>` it will add a line break. While this would suit in this case, there are probably cases where I want to avoid line breaks. What then?

Comment: Also, you can indent multi-line code with 4 spaces (Ctrl+K) and wrap inline code in backticks (also Ctrl+K).

Comment: @nixda In cases like the question you linked to it'd probably make sense to use a bulleted list and not use code formatting at all — after all, it's not code or some command here, but just the names of some settings.

Comment: Though `<pre>` (currently) is styled using a fixed-width font, I'd say for code one should use `<pre><code>`. (Which is exactly what using the four spaces Markdown gets one. Using the four spaces also gets one automatic encoding of HTML entities such as changing `<strong>` into `&lt;strong&gt;`.)

Comment: @Arjan True, that is the semantically correct way. The problem is that after `<pre><code>` you'll get an extra line break if you start the code on the next line.